How to use Thread outside of scope
I have this code. I want to make it so that if is_media_playing is True it joins the playthread
import dbus
from time import sleep
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play
import threading

song = AudioSegment.from_mp3("Tron Legacy - Soundtrack OST - 04 Recognizer - Daft Punk [j1eI-7XWjho].mp3")

def play_song():
    play(song)


def is_media_playing():
    bus = dbus.SessionBus()
    for service in bus.list_names():
        if service.startswith('org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.'):
            player = dbus.SessionBus().get_object(service, '/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2')
            status = player.Get('org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player', 'PlaybackStatus', dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties')
            if status == 'Playing':
                return True
    return False


def check():
    while True:
        if is_media_playing():
            print("Media is playing")

        else:
            print("Media is not playing")
            playThread = threading.Thread(target=play_song, args=())
            playThread.start()

        sleep(3)


if __name__ =="__main__": 
    checkThread = threading.Thread(target=check, args=())
    checkThread.start()
    

I tried to define playThread in the start but then it says that a thread can only be started once.

You might add an attribute to function check() check.playfunc =  playThread that is visible at an outer scope so you can refer to it from main() like check.playfunc.join()

I am not sure I understood what you want, but if it is to join the playthread when (so that it waits until it is over) - you can modify your check function like this
def check():
    playThread = None
    while True:
        if is_media_playing():
            print("Media is playing")
            if playThread:
                 playThread.join() #waits until playthreads finishes execution
                 playThread = None

        else:
            print("Media is not playing")
            playThread = threading.Thread(target=play_song, args=())
            playThread.start()

        sleep(3)


